# Audio Conversion: Nesting loops in batch file gives no output

Tags: batch-file, nested-loops, sox

I'm converting a couple thousand .wem files to .wav format. Since .wem is an obscure file format, I've decided to convert the files with SoX.

The SoX standard installation includes a batch file for use with mass converting raw files, which I've happily used. I've modified the example to remove the need to drag and drop files onto the batch file, using nested loops.

```
cd %~dp0
mkdir converted
for %%f in (*.wem) do FOR %%A IN (%*) DO sox -t raw -e signed-integer -b 16 -c 1 -r 44100 %%A "converted/%%~nA.wav"
pause
```

It creates a /converted directory just fine, and then proceeds to output the command, the directory, and then moves on to (supposedly) the next file. Unfortunately, opening the /converted directory reveals that nothing was generated at all, and the conversion took a lot less time than it should have. I've tested it with .wem files prior, and it converts just fine, so I don't think it has anything to do with the format. More likely, it just has something to do with my amateur batch file programming. Any ideas?

Comment: `FOR %%A IN (%%f) DO..` but I do not understand why you require the two for loops when it can be achieved in one loop.

Comment: How would I go about implementing it in a single loop? There are multiple conditionals, and they can only be passed in multiple loops, right?

Comment: The first line should be `cd "%~dp0"` to work also on batch file path containing `&`. The __FOR__ loop should be `for %%I in (*.wem) do sox.exe -t raw -e signed-integer -b 16 -c 1 -r 44100 "%%I" "converted\%%~nI.wav"` if `sox` is a file with file extension `.exe`. Otherwise with `sox` having file extension `.bat` or `.cmd` replace `sox.exe` by `call sox.bat` respectively `call sox.cmd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks to [Mofi.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi)

Finished code:

```
cd %~dp0
mkdir converted
for %%I in (*.wem) do sox -t raw -e signed-integer -b 16 -c 1 -r 44100 "%%I" "converted\%%~nI.wav"
pause
```

Seems I really could do it in one loop.

Comment: See.. Single for loop :)